# How to overcome org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, exception

I keep receiving connectivity issues when connecting my Spring project to a MySQL server.  I have tried various tricks that I have found online but to no avail.  I need help in order to escape this quandary. I'm placing my Spring settings below and the stack trace as well.

Spring Settings

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initialize=true
spring.dataSource.tomcat.url=jdbc:mysql://nope/canttellyou?
autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.dataSource.tomcat.username=nope
spring.dataSource.tomcat.password=sorry
spring.dataSource.tomcat.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1 
spring.datasource.tomcat.log-validation-errors=true
```

StackTrace

```
stackTrace: org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: 
PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select catname from animals]; The last 
packet successfully received from the server was 52,962,310 
milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 
52,962,310 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value 
of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing 
connection validity before use in your application, increasing the 
server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J 
connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.; nested 
exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
The last packet successfully received from the server was 52,962,310 
milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 
52,962,310 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value 
of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing 
connection validity before use in your application, increasing the 
server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J 
connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem.  I think the configuration setting we want to turn on is:

```
testWhileIdle
```

Here's the related [tomcat connection pool docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jdbc-pool.html)

I won't know until tomorrow whether or not this worked for me.